# CSSで @max- :unit(); という記述のしかたって？

Tags: css

差し迫った問題というわけではなく、雑談レベルでの質問なのですが、
このサイト ( http://www.redbull.tv/) のCSSを見ていて `@max-` という
今まで見たことのない記述がありました。

```
@max- 600:unit((599 * 0.0625),em) @max-540:unit((539 * 0.0625),em);
```

ググっても周りの人に聞いてもまったくわかりません。
どなたかご存知の方はいませんか？

参考: 該当CSS (1行目)
http://www.redbull.tv/assets/main.bundle-b018991b2c063acb3bd2.css

Comment: LESSの構文なのですね。
LESSを書いたことがなく気づきませんでした。  

変数名に半角スペースがまざっているようなので、それが原因による
コンパイルエラーですかね。  

すっきりしました。  
ありがとうございました！

Comment: それぞれの回答の下にもコメント欄がありますから、回答へのコメントにはそちらをお使いください。質問のコメント欄は質問者に対するコメントに使われることが多いです。 / 質問が解決した場合は、役に立った回答（複数あればどれかひとつ）の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックして解決済みのマークを付けていただけると助かります（このサイトでは「承認」と呼んでいます）。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。解決済みのチェックとコメントを書き直しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unit()が続いてますし、LESS変数の変換残りな気がします。

Comment: なるほど、LESS構文なのですね。書いたことないので気づきませんでした。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

CSS としては文法間違いです。

[LESS](http://less-ja.studiomohawk.com/)での変数 `@max-600` と `@max-540` を定義しているように見えますが、何かの手違いで CSS ファイルに残っているのでしょう。

Comment: LESSだと `@` が変数なんですね。 `@max- 600` がエラーの原因っぽいですね。ありがとうございます！